# How print list with all columns?

Tags: pandas

I have two DataFrame where it has 108 columns and another 107 columns.

I want to compare these columns because they should be the same and there is a non-compliance.

As there are many columns when using `df.columns` or `df.info ()` the list with the columns is not displayed.

Can anyone tell me how I could make this comparison?

Or at least how to display the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the difference using set

```
print(list(set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns)))
```